# How to backtrack in regular expression

Tags: regex, backtracking, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to validate url which doesn't contain **login** before **.com** at the end, but the regex at [here](http://rubular.com/r/eRdZwvxYIq) is not validating the url properly.

I've used the lazy quantifier, but it is still consuming **login** string before moving to `(?!login)` part, and it is not backtracking.  Could anyone please tell me what wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/vUVc1FCfTa) is a changed version, that says "Match some characters ; immediately preceding the end is *not* `"login"`, and immediately following *is* `".com"`.

The problem in your part was: you had two lookaheads, looking ahead from the same position. It read: "some string, that is followed by something that *at the same time* is not `"login"` and is `".com"`. Indeed, `".com"` is not `"login"`, so that's what you matched.

Comment: You don't need that look-ahead on `.com` part.

Comment: @RohitJain: It all depends what you need to match. OP used it, so I continue to use it. If I didn't, the matched string would be 4 characters longer.